# JSON not fetching success on codeigniter - [object Object]

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

What i'm trying to do here to populate second select from based from the first one with json format.

Everything goes okay i'm getting the results i need with exact num of rows from the model based on the ID which i send with the request but i have this error :

[image: http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/8895/ng1g.png "error"]

I'm trying to get the mark id based on the model selected which i have in database :

```
ID MARK_ID VALUE_MARK
```

Here is my jquery function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#mark").change(function() {
   var markId= $("#mark").val();
   if (markId!= "") {
     $.get(
    'upload/car_models?mark_id=' + markId,
    function(data){                     
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
               $("#model").append("<option value='" + key + "'>" + value + "</option>");
        })
    },
    "json"
);
   }
});
})
```

And in my controller i'm doing json encode like this for the variable which is back from the model

```
echo json_encode($models);
```

How can i fix this problem with object Object.
Thanks. Any help will be appreciate.
**EDIT :**
Json structure :

```
[{"id":"50","mark_id":"50","value_mark":"Refine","value":"JAC"},     {"id":"50","mark_id":"50","value_mark":"Rein","value":"JAC"}]
```

Here is my json structure. id mark_id value_mark here have 2 rows returned from the model

Comment: provide your json structure???

Comment: [{"id":"50","mark_id":"50","value_mark":"Refine","value":"JAC"},{"id":"50","mark_id":"50","value_mark":"Rein","value":"JAC"}]

Here is my json structure. id mark_id value_mark here have 2 rows returned from the model

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mark").change(function() {
        var markId= $("#mark").val();
        if (markId!= "") {
            $.get(
                'upload/car_models?mark_id=' + markId,
                function(data){   
                    var model=$("#model");
                    model.empty();
                    $.each(data, function(key, val){
                        model.append("<option value='" + val.value + "'>" + val.value_mark + "</option>");
                    });
                },
                "json"
                );
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is an array of objects. WHen you loop over that array with `$.each` `key` will be index, and `value` will be object at that index.

Try:

```
$.each(data, function(i, obj){
      $("#model").append("<option value='" + obj.value + "'>" + obj.value_mark + "</option>");
 });
```

I guessed at what properties you want to assign to `<option>` value and text

Comment: This works great. But when select ex. Audi all audi models are listed but then if i select Volvo the Audi models stays still there + the volvo models are added above. How can i fix this

Comment: before the each loop, remove old ones using `$("#model").empty()`

Comment: Thanks charlietfl this works great now. I will adjust just a little. But i need a little explanation about the i, obj in each data function what this means and how this fixed my problem.
Thanks again

Comment: when looping an array first argument of `$.each` is `index`, second is the array element. Can name those arguments anything you want, I just used `i` to represent `index` and `obj` since the array element is an object, not a string or number etc

Comment: if you were looping an obbject with `$.each` , first argument would be the property key, second is value of that key

Comment: Yeah i understand you now. Thank you again finally solved this problem

Comment: when in doubt use `console.log(variable)` to help see what you are working with

Comment: I will have that on mind in future. Btw just curious what solution is better to insert the model name into database according to the ID ex. 254 which is = Z5 or like varchar like just Z5 in my field.